# How to set multiple conditions on the same column in the WHERE clause in postgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a data table like the name as `acc_journal_details` and sample data are like below

[image]

Here I need two `sql`

1. `where chart_of_accounts_id = 94`

[image]

2. `where chart_of_accounts_id = 98`

[image]

Comment: Where does debit value 950000 come from? Edit: or is it 9500000? Provide sample table data and expected result as properly formatted text instead of images, so we can copy-and-paste data and column names etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `in`

```
where chart_of_accounts_id in ( 94,98)
```

or concat the conditions with `OR`

```
where chart_of_accounts_id = 94 or chart_of_accounts_id =  98
```